# Health forum data sets

Tags: data-request, medical, nlp

I am looking for data sets that contain health-related forum posts. Ideally, with as much structured information as possible (post, post timestamp, poster ID, history of edits, etc.). I know I can crawl fora myself but I would prefer to have ready-to-use data sets.

Comment: I know the folks at http://corp.treato.com/ have done this scraping and some NLP/extraction from it.. no idea if they would be willing to share. I can't think of any free and open sources of this data, sorry

Comment: What about twitter: https://twitter.com/twitterdata/status/519562363188432896